# How can I print data from X.m to listbox in GUI in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have program.m file that contains:

```
for i=1:k
  V=geAllThreeElements(n);
  fprintf('total is %d\n',size(V,1));
end
```

and I have tst.fig that contain Push Button that call program function and listox

I want print ('total is %d\n',size(V,1)) in list box not in command windows during program function execution, How?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right, you are calling a m-file (script) from a pushbutton within a figure.

First of all you should return the Data of the variable you called "V". If you dont use programm.m as a function and you totally dont want to do that, you have to get "V" by loading it into your the workspace of your GUI.

See **assignin** for example!

now that you have the Data of V, you can use it to display information about it within a listbox like this:

```
%you have to know the handle of the listbox-> I call it myLB:
%if you want to append data:    
myData = get(myLB, String)
set(myLB, String, [myData sprintf('total is %d\n',size(V,1))])
%if you want to replace data:
set(myLB, String, sprintf('total is %d\n',size(V,1)))
```